# How to type vendor specific property in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

How can I type this connection type here? Is there any helper type? I am not able to find an answer in `lib.dom.d.ts`

```js
    const connection = navigator.connection || navigator.mozConnection || navigator.webkitConnection;
```

The error I am getting

```js
Error: Property 'mozConnection' does not exist on type 'Navigator'.
export const useConnection = (): void => {
        const connection = navigator.connection || navigator.mozConnection || navigator.webkitConnection;


Error: Property 'webkitConnection' does not exist on type 'Navigator'.
export const useConnection = (): void => {
        const connection = navigator.connection || navigator.mozConnection || navigator.webkitConnection
```

Comment: Wonder if passing navigator as any would solve it?  My day has been the pain of working with loosely typed objects in strongly typed languages as well, good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extend `Navigator` interface. It will be merged with the lib.dom declaration. [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgHJwG7AOZzAeymQG8AoZC5AW3wC8BhfEECBMYJgfgC41Mc8hANoAiBExZsOIEQF1ylAO4QARgGtgYRs1bsuvdFlwEoo8TqlM5pAL6ly5gM5hk5yXpDIAvMhD9jhAB0brrSyAA%204b7%20glCBNAwSoUwRUX5GsYHK6pra7tIA3EA)

```
interface Navigator {
    mozConnection?: Navigator["connection"]
    webkitConnection?: Navigator["connection"]
}

 const connection = navigator.connection || navigator.mozConnection || navigator.webkitConnection;
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I have added the following as well after applied your answer, maybe someone might need this
`interface NetworkInformation {
    readonly rtt: number;
    readonly downlink: number;
}`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `declare` to specify it:

```
declare const navigator: any;  // declaration you need
const connection = navigator.connection || navigator.mozConnection || navigator.webkitConnection;
```

Works for me.